# Setting default-time-zone on MySql Server via PhPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, timezone

I have a shared hosting mySql instance which has it's system_time_zone set to Pacific Standard Time and it's time_zone variable set to System, hence effectively it's running on Pacific Standard Time.

i.e. I've run the following command to find this out:

```
SELECT version( ) , @@time_zone , @@system_time_zone , NOW( ) , UTC_TIMESTAMP( )
```

I would like to change the default mySql database / local mySql DB time-zone to GMT/UTC time. I tried to run, `SET time_zone = '+0:00'`, and this does execute successfully!

However, this does not seem to affect the time_zone variable, when I check the state of @@time_zone. I've looked at another post dealing with similar issue [How to set MySQL to use GMT in Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437712/how-to-set-mysql-to-use-gmt-in-windows-and-linux) and I also checked the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), with little progress. Since I am on a shared-hosting solution, I have limited access and I don't have access to more than what my PhPMyAdmin mySql functionality has on offer.

I wonder if there is any way to change the default_time-zone from within an SQL query, or do I need to fall back to the command line (to which I don't have access to, unfortunately).

Thanks for your help and advice,

Martin

Comment: Have you tried SET SESSION time_zone = '+0:00' or SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+0:00'?

Comment: thanks for the tip 'client09', but unfortunatelly I get "#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation", not enough privileges on shared hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For shared hosting, you have to ask support-guys to help you and change default time zone for you? I had similar problem with Arcor hosting-provider, called them and they fixed it. Before that, I found temporary solution in `date_default_timezone_set()` from PHP code. Probably the best solution is to ask someone who has privilege to change that parameter.

Comment: I think in my shared hosting situation this is probably the wisest thing to do. I contacted them, and unfortunatelly they declined to change the default time zone for me. I found this strange, but I didnt follow it up, since I just then decided to convert all my times to UTC on server side and just work with UTC instead, this seems to be working.

Answer (score 8):

In short, `MySQL` actually stores '`datetime`' data type fields internally as `UTC`.

`However`, `PhpMyAdmin` shows you the dates using the server default time, hence your confusion.

For example, try adding this line before your SQL statement in `PhpMyAdmin`:

```
SET @@session.time_zone='+00:00';
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
```

See the `MySQL` documentation for further details, or the answer in this post: [How to correctly set mysql timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434030/how-to-correctly-set-mysql-timezone)

Cheers
Matt

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); //define local time

$date=date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); //type of time shown

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect!'); //your database connection here

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('databasename', $conn); //select db

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (date) VALUES ('$date')", $conn); 
?>
```

Simply sent the time as VARCHAR into db hope it helps and sorry for syntax errors (if there are any).