# Change timezone in my phpmyadmin shared server

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I need to change my timezone to India timezone, but my shared server database showing some junk timezone I tried all the possibility but I can't get the India time zone.

**I am using PHP Codeigniter**

I Have a contact us page on my website, which saves all the send inquiry details to my mail and database. on that is showing some junk time on it

please help me out of this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of shared hosting you would need to contact support guys or go for a live chat and they can change the default time zone for you.

You can use `date_default_timezone_set()` which sets a default timezone.

Please give a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381581/setting-default-time-zone-on-mysql-server-via-phpmyadmin)

**OR**

convert all your times to UTC on server side and just work with UTC instead

**EDITED ANSWER**

What you can do is :

Store your date time in DB in UTC, and while showing You can show Date time By getting current timezone of India.

```
// create a $dt object with the UTC timezone
$dt = new DateTime('2016-12-12 12:12:12', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// change the timezone of the object without changing it's time
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

// format the datetime
$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T');
```

Comment: I have used date_default_timezone_set() on index.php file on application->views folder but still not working

Comment: what is your purpose  to doing that?

Comment: i Have a contactus page on my website, which saving all the send enquiry  details to my mail and database. on that is is showing some junk time on it