# UK Timezone (GMT) - PHP date or MySQL date?

Tags: php, mysql, database, timezone

I have developed a website in PHP and MySQL. the website is for UK customers only to purchase products and stuff.

I've used `NOW()` function in the mySQL query to insert current date & time.

In PHP, I have included this in the header:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Is there anything else I might have missed to setup UK Timezone properly?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the MySQL timezone using this: [How to set MySQL to use GMT in Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437712/how-to-set-mysql-to-use-gmt-in-windows-and-linux)

And you could make sure your servers time zone is also set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set time zone from the following query in mySQL:

```
select name from mysql.time_zone_name;
```